# How to check if any values in a list are within a given tolerance of some value

Tags: python, pandas

I should append a number `x` in a list called `y` if in `y` there are not number that are in the neighborhood of `x`.

For example, if I have: `y = [1, 1.5, 1.7, 2.1, 3]` I need to append a number that is not in the range +/-0.1 of the number in the list.

So I will append `x = 3.2`, but not append `x =3.05`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is probably [`np.isclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html)

```
# For x = 3.2
>>> ~np.isclose(y, x, atol=0.1).any()
True

# For x = 3.05
>>> ~np.isclose(y, x, atol=0.1).any()
False
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the range condition applies to all the list elements or only the last one, here's the example of both:

```
def foo(lst:list, value, dif=0.1):
    clos = min(lst, key=lambda lst : abs(lst - value))
    if abs(clos - value) > dif:
        lst.append(value)
    return lst
foo(y, 3.2)
Output: [1, 1.5, 1.7, 2.1, 3, 3.2]
```

Or only to last element:

```
def foo(lst:list, value, dif=0.1):
    if abs(value - lst[-1]) > dif:
        lst.append(value)
    return lst
```